# Create custom pipable operator in RXJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

As far as I know these two approaches for creating custom operator both works, which one is better and why?

the **lettable** approach

```
logger(message) {
    return (source) => {
        return source.pipe(tap(res => console.log(message)))
    }
}
```

using **pipe** function

```
logger(message) {
    return pipe(tap(res => console.log(message)))
}
```

Comment: "Better" is usually moot unless you specify usage context. However, the second utility-based [`pipe()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/util/pipe.ts) form is particularly useful when you want to compose existing pipes into a unified one (e.g. `const p = pipe(p1, p2, p3); observable.pipe(p).subscribe();`). You can't really do this with the first form because the return result is an observable.

Comment: the usage context is nothing really in particular, just in general usage. the first approach do what you says too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are correct and both a pipable. The word "lettable" was used only for very short time and it was changed to "pipable" by RxJS core devs: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md

The only difference between the two variants is that the first one gives you more freedom in what you want to do because you have access to `source` so you can for example subscribe to it yourself and return a different Observable. The second variant is just a shortcut for a chain of operators you want to reuse multiple times so you don't have to copy & paste it.